# characterization of weakly convergent to zero sequences on $l^p$ for $1\le p < \infty$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $1\le p< \infty$. Show that a sequence $t_k = ({t_{kj}})_{j=1}^{\infty}\in l^p$ converges weakly to 0 iff $||t_k||_p$ is bounded and $\lim_k t_{kj}=0$.  I proved that if $t_k$ converges weakly to 0 then we conclude that. I want to prove the reciprocal.

Let's assume that $1<p<\infty$ If I assume that $(t_k)$ it's weakly cauchy I can prove that it's weakly convergento to 0, but I don't know how to prove that. Under that assumption I used the reflexivity of the space $l^p$ ($l^1$ is not reflexive)

If $p=1$ since $l^1$ is not reflexive my arguments are not valid here. I don't really now if the result it's also true here. Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a proof of more general result [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239862/boundedness-and-pointwise-convergence-imply-weak-convergence-in-ellp?rq=1).

Appply that theorem to the case $p\in(1,+\infty)$ with $S=\{f_j\in (\ell_p)^*:j\in\mathbb{N}\}$, where 
$$
f_j:\ell_p\to\mathbb{K}: t\mapsto t_j
$$

For $p=1$ see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42609/strong-and-weak-convergence-in-ell1), where it was proved that weak convergence is equivalent to strong convergence. It is remains to note that every strongly convergent sequence is bounded and pointwise convergent.

Comment: Thanks Norbert for the complete answer! But I have one question! why the span of the projections are dense?

Comment: span of projections is the space of finitely supported vectors usually denoted by $c_{00}$. It is dense in $\ell_p$ by the following argument. For a given $\varepsilon$ and $t\in\ell_p$ there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\sum_{j=N+1}^\infty|t_j|^p<\varepsilon^p$. Then consider $y\in c_{00}$ such that $y_j=t_j$ for $j=1,\ldots,N$ and $y_j=0$ otherwise. Then $\Vert t- y\Vert_p<\varepsilon$.

Comment: You are right, thanks!

Comment: But note that for the case $p=1$ the dual of $l^1$ is $l^{\infty}$ and here $c_{00}$ is not dense on $l^{\infty}$ so the span of the projections are not dense on $(l^1)'$

Comment: @Shanks, you are right. See edits to my answer.